# How to create a "dynamic HtmlHelper" in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I made a **sample** class:

```
public class Sample
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Sample(int id, string value)
    {
        Id = id;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

In my **Controller** I made a list of objects of type Sample class:

```
public class FormControlsController : Controller
{
    // GET: FormControls
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Sample> samples = new List<Sample>();
        samples.Add(new Sample(1, "Foo"));
        samples.Add(new Sample(2, "Bar"));
        ViewBag.samples = samples;
        return View();
    }
}
```

My **View** contains the following code:

`@FormHelper.CreateInput("select", "", "", ViewBag.samples)`

Which should pass the list of `Sample` objects to the following `FormHelper` method called `CreateInput()`:

```
public static class FormHelper
{
    // A method to create inputs with the according bootstrap element structure and classes
    public static HtmlString CreateInput(string inputType, string label = "label", string placeholder = "", List<T> options = null)
    {
        string html = "";
        if (inputType == "text")
        {
            html = "<div class='form-group'><label for=''>" + label + "</label><input type='text' class='form-control' id='' placeholder='" + placeholder + "'></div>";
        }
        else if (inputType == "select")
        {    
            html = "<div class='form-group'><label for='exampleInputEmail1'>" + label + "</label><select class='form-control' id=''><option selected disabled hidden>-- Select an option --</option>";
            if (options.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string option in options)
                {
                    html += "<option value='" + option.Id + "'>" + option.Value + "</option>";
                }
            }
            html += "</select></div>";
        }
        // Irrelevant for this question, but for context purpose
        else if (inputType == "radio")
        {    
            //radioOptions.Add("Foo");
            //radioOptions.Add("Bar");

            html = "<div class='form-group'><label for=''>" + label + "</label>";
            if (radioOptions.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string radioOption in radioOptions)
                {
                    html += "<div class='radio'><label><input type='radio'>" + radioOption + "</label></div>";
                }
            }
            html += "</div>";
        }
        return new HtmlString(html);
    }
}
```

The sample list is just as it says, an example. I am trying to pass any list of any kind of type (so not just a list of `Sample` type).

The compiler will obviously generate a compiler error stating `CreateInput()` method does not assign its type and generic type could not be converted to a string.

How could I address these problems? How could I pass different lists with different objects and loop through these within the `CreateInput()` method?

Comment: yikes. that screams to need a partial.

Comment: Could you elaborate what your solution might look like to such problem? @DanielA.White